# iframe source not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

Here is my source code - 
HTML:

```
<div class="row no-label print">
   <center>
     <iframe id="aframeSmpl" width="775" height="85" frameborder="0">
     </iframe>
   </center>
</div>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('aframeSmpl').src = "//banner.agoda.com/js/show_ads.js?agoda_ad_client=1597217_1&agoda_ad_width=728&agoda_ad_height=90&agoda_ad_language=1&agoda_ad_checkin=2016-05-25&agoda_ad_checkout=2016-05-26&agoda_ad_currency=USD&agoda_ad_hotelcategory=midrange&agoda_ad_iata=SIN";
```

This should generate a dynamic image from the source. Unfortunately, a javascript function is displayed on the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you JS code to this.

```js
document.getElementById('aframeSmpl').src = "https://banner.agoda.com/js/show_ads.js%3Fagoda_ad_client=1597217_1&agoda_ad_width=728&agoda_ad_height=90&agoda_ad_language=1&agoda_ad_checkin=2016-05-25&agoda_ad_checkout=2016-05-26&agoda_ad_currency=USD&agoda_ad_hotelcategory=midrange&agoda_ad_iata=SIN";
```

```html
<div class="row no-label print">
   <center>
     <iframe id="aframeSmpl" width="775" height="85" frameborder="0">
     </iframe>
   </center>
</div>
```

You must add `https://` in the url of JS if you are fetching from remote.

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhzovfm5/)

Answer (score 0):

//banner.agoda.com/js/show_ads.js?agoda_ad_client=1597217_1&agoda_ad_width=728&agoda_ad_height=90&agoda_ad_language=1&agoda_ad_checkin=2016-05-25&agoda_ad_checkout=2016-05-26&agoda_ad_currency=USD&agoda_ad_hotelcategory=midrange&agoda_ad_iata=SIN